# How would you prove that $n^1 = n$ every time?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This may seem like a trivial question but, how would you prove, mathematically, that any number raised to the power of $1$ is always that number?

Comment: What is your definition of $n^1$?

Comment: What carmichael said.  You need to use your definition of exponentiation to do this.  What you can prove depends on what definition you use.  For example (to be perverse), in complex analysis we use the definition $x^y = \exp(y\log x)$.  But from that we cannot prove $0^1 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

No need to prove this by the recursive definition of powers we have 
$
n^1=n
$
for all n. 
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation for a reference.